# Access a shared local folder with html

Tags: html, windows-7

On our network, I want to share a folder where I will store my data such as images and videos.
I want host our html in the cloud and reference the assets locally.

I have shared a folder called test and the pathway is:

```
<img src="//JOHNATHAN-PC/chevron_test/images/star.jpg" />
```

Anyone on their ipads will just navigate to the website and view the assets like a normal webpage so long as they are on the local network.

It was working with the syntax above and after a power failure it stopped.
I am using windows 7.

Comment: Sounds like your webserver isn't running.

Comment: I though that this was the case, I started a local wamp instance and the script works for PC based users, but not tablet or smartphones. It was before the crash.

Comment: The error as to why the resource is not being displayed is Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Answer (score 0):

My DNS name wasn't being registered on our server. Simpler answer was actually from ceejayoz. Using a static IP and a webserver I was able to access the shared folder.